# Mongodb: unwind to a property with a different name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using c# fluent api I built a query aggregate with lookup and unwind stages.
I join a first collection with Badge collection where there is a 1:1 relationship.

I have the following intermediate classes for building strongly typed query

```
public class AfterLookupClass
{
    ...
    public IEnumerable<Badge> badges { get; set; }
}
public class AfterUnwindClass
{
    ...
    public Badge badges { get; set; }
}
```

The relevant part of the aggregate query is the following:

```
Lookup<FirstClass, Badge, AfterLookupClass>(
foreignCollection: BadgeCollection, 
localField: e => e.Codice, 
foreignField: f => f.Codice, 
@as: (AfterLookupClasse eo) => eo.badges).
Unwind<AfterLookupClass, AfetrUnwindClass>(el => el.badges)
```

If in the AfterUnwindClass I change the name of the property from **badges** to something else, for example a more appropriate **badge** (it is expected to be only one) the query doesn't work anymore.
Is it possible to **unwind** to a property with a different name ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using a lookup syntax with [pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-join-pipeline) (also supported via c# driver) or to use `Project` stage between `Lookup` and `Unwind`